# How to get count of distinct values from two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below and I want to count distinct values from two columns (fruit1 and fruit2)

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| s_id | s_name | fruit1 | fruit2 | rs   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|    1 | ram    | apple  | mango  |   20 |
|    2 | raj    | apple  | banana |   13 |
|    3 | aman   | orange | banana |    7 |
|    4 | mangal | orange | apple  |   16 |
|    5 | ravi   | apple  | banana |   17 |
|    6 | pawan  | apple  | apple  |    9 |
|    7 | shyam  | apple  | orange |   11 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

I am able to do this for one column using below command, but not success for two column, not getting how to achieve this.

> select fruit1, count(*) as count from s_info group by fruit1;

which results in

```
+--------+-------+
| fruit1 | count |
+--------+-------+
| apple  |     5 |
| orange |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```

But below is my expected result, which I am not getting.

```
+--------+-------+
| fruits | count |
+--------+-------+
| apple  |     7 |
| orange |     3 |
| banana |     3 |
| mango  |     1 |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `union all` before doing the final aggregation:

```
select fruit, count(*)
from ((select fruit1 as fruit from s_info) union all
      (select fruit2 as fruit from s_info)
     ) i
group by fruit;
```